# Write SeqIO Dictionary as Fasta File

Tags: python, dictionary, biopython, fasta

I originally converted my fasta sequence into a dictionary with a Bio.SeqIO.to_dict statement. I would like to write a subsetted dictionary back to a fasta file.

Test is a python dictionary with fasta headers as keys and the sequences as indexes.

My code attempting to utilize SeqIO.write:

```
with open("example.fasta", "w") as handle:
SeqIO.write(test, handle, "fasta")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I am afraid by converting the SeqIO generator object to a dictionary, I am unable to easily return to the inputs expected by other SeqIO functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue. Even with the SeqIO.to_dict conversion, the values of the dictionary are the original generator class. To write this dictionary back to a Fasta simply call the values of the dictionary.

```py
with open("example.fasta", "w") as handle:
    SeqIO.write(test.values(), handle, "fasta")
```